# delayed_job process stops running after a while

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, delayed-job

Once I deploy, the delayed_job worker spawns and works perfectly - but after around 1.5 days to 2 days it just stops working.

Right now I have to redeploy the application every morning just to ensure that the queue is actually completed each day. I can't seem to find what's wrong in the production logs.

Here is my script for re-starting the worker upon deployment:

```
files:
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_restart_delayed_job.sh":
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
  #!/usr/bin/env bash
  # Using similar syntax as the appdeploy pre hooks that is managed by AWS

  # Loading environment data
  EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k script_dir)
  EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k support_dir)
  EB_APP_USER=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user)
  EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_deploy_dir)
  EB_APP_PIDS_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_pid_dir)

  # Setting up correct environment and ruby version so that bundle can load all gems
  . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
  . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

  # Now we can do the actual restart of the worker. Make sure to have double quotes when using env vars in the command.
  # For Rails 4, replace script/delayed_job with bin/delayed_job
  cd $EB_APP_CURRENT_DIR
  su -s /bin/bash -c "bundle exec bin/delayed_job --pid-dir=$EB_APP_PIDS_DIR restart" $EB_APP_USER
```

And here is the production log, as you can see it starts the worker successfully, but it says no previous process was running, even though I deployed the app three days ago.

```
[2018-08-13T07:02:26.297Z] INFO  [6232]  - [Application update app-bdb6-180813_085933@169/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/99_restart_delayed_job.sh] : Starting activity...
[2018-08-13T07:02:28.359Z] INFO  [6232]  - [Application update app-bdb6-180813_085933@169/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/99_restart_delayed_job.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
delayed_job: warning: no instances running. Starting...
delayed_job: process with pid 8947 started.
```

I'm using `delayed_job (4.1.5)` and `delayed_job_active_record (4.1.3)`.

Comment: What sort of error messages are you seeing in your logs?

Comment: @EmilKampp that’s the weird thing, I don’t see any errors or any occurrence of delayed_job in the logs

Comment: How about syslog?